# AttributeError: module 'jaxlib' has no attribute 'version'

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, conda, jax

I was trying to upgrade `jaxlib` to the newest version but it failed. So I first uninstalled it via Conda with `conda remove --force jaxlib`. and then installed it with `conda install -c conda-forge jaxlib`.

Now it is giving me an error I have no clue how to solve!

```
AttributeError: module 'jaxlib' has no attribute 'version'
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include in the question body the output from `conda list jax`, so we could see your versions. As implied by @jakevdp's answer, it's possible the combination of `jax` and `jaxlib` are incompatible. If your goal is Python use, as the error implies, you should be updating `jax` (the Python library) not `jaxlib` (the compiled library) and let Conda sort the correct dependencies for you.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by one of two things:

1. if your `jaxlib` installation is too old, it may not be compatible with the version of `jax` you have installed. Check the versions to be sure they're compatible (the most recent versions of `jax` and `jaxlib` are 0.3.13 and 0.3.10, respectively)
2. This may indicate that `conda remove` did not entirely remove the library artifacts from your system, and that you're somehow importing an incompletely-installed pacakge. If this is the case, you should be able to examine the `jaxlib` path mentioned in the full error traceback and make sure everything is there.